# Trying to fetch instagram feeds for my website

Tags: php

I am using instagram feeds on my website, but due to traffic it is showing error as:

> You have exceeded the maximum number of requests per hour. You have performed a total of 694 requests in the last hour. Our general maximum limit is set at 500 requests per hour

Comment: What do you want help with? It is telling you the problem, there is a limit and you reached it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cache your result from Instagram and update cache every hour. User will see cache without another request to your instagram feed api.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are still in sandbox.  Switch to LIVE where they allow 5,000 requests per hour?

[Global Rate Limits](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/)

> Global rate limits are applied inclusive of all API calls made by an app per access token over the 1-hour sliding window, regardless of the particular endpoint. Rate limits also apply to invalid or malformed requests. Client Status   Rate Limit:
>   **Sandbox   500 / hour**, 
>   **Live  5000 / hour**